# CRM Plug-In Call retrieves a subset of Invoice Lines when creating an Invoice from an order

Tags: integration, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are developing a CRM plug-in that would be triggered whenever an Invoice is Generated in CRM from an Order.

The typical action would be going to a Sales Order and clicking on “Create an Invoice”.

The end game of the plug-in is to integrate the Invoice into a Remote system along with the header and lines.

Plug-in works in the following way:

1. Plugin is registered with the CRM Invoice for the “Create” Event.
2. Plugin runs “Asynchronously” via a Post operation of the Invoice Header.
3. Upon hitting “Create Invoice”, UI Action; Plugin sends the newly created Invoice GUID to a service, this is typically a POST operation:

a.       We Basically make a call to an ASPX page which accepts this request and processes it.

b.      Processing includes steps by:

i. Getting the invoice header through a CRM Service Retrieve call.

ii. Getting the Invoice Lines through a CRM Service Retrieve multiple call.

c.       Commit the Invoice to the 3rd Remote Application Database.

d.      We respond to the Plug-in by wrapping any custom status or error messages.

1. All the processes finishes in less than a minute.

Scenarios We tested on our end:

Case 1:

Invoice Containing 5-10 Lines

Steps 3(a).  till 3(d). runs successfully and integrated the Invoice with all the lines.

Case 2: ISSUE

Invoice Containing more than 10 (Tested with 15-40 lines)

Step 3b(ii) . Invoice Lines Retrieval process retrieves only some lines and not all the lines

Initially we thought, there could be a Read lock for the current Authenticated user for CRM SDK, as the logged in user was also same, when the CRM is creating lines for the Invoice.

But the test failed there too.

Successful Scenario Tested:

We retrieved the Invoice Lines separately through a different call by delaying the call for some seconds. The number of lines retrieved was successful. But not sure what delay the server would take.

We require your inputs on this issue to move forward in order to resolve this as we may be making some mistakes while doing this Plugin request call.

Thanks And Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a year old but I'm still looking for a solution to it so I figure other people might be too.

My experience is that CRM needs to save (Create) the header record before it can associate the lines to it. Because you have registered it for Async execution, there is a slight delay before it executes which gives it time to have saved some of the lines before you try and load them.

So far my best solution is to trigger the plugin on the Create message of invoicelines, count all of the lines associated with that invoice and either pass a row count from the order or count the lines on the order and when they have the same count, execute your main body of code. It is pretty inefficient for orders with a lot of rows. But it is *a* solution.